# Glassfish 3.1.2.2 file upload

Tags: java, javascript, spring, apache, glassfish

I'm having an issue when I try to upload a file in my application.

The application server is Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

Server side I'm using Spring MVC. So I declared in `beans.xml` :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

In the controller, I have :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object processUpload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    ... do something with request.getFiles(...); ...
}
```

On the client side, I'm using `XMLHttpRequest` :

```
xhr.open('POST', url, true);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('something', ...);
formData.append('file', file);
```

It's working with small files but with larges files, it keeps giving me this exception message :

```
Stream ended unexpectedly
```

What I tried :

- `max-post-size-bytes="0"` or `max-post-size-bytes="1073741824"` (= 1go / test-file = 300mo) in domains.xml
- change web-core.jar with the one provided in https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18444
- change commons-io, commons-fileupload with the ones in glassfish/libs
- change web-core independantly / change commons libs independantly
- use `<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver">` instead of commons-fileupload + `<multipart-config>` in web.xml

Thanks in advance,

Smoky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution :

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/processUpload',
    data : formData,
    dataType : 'text',
    cache : false,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    xhr : function () {
        ... progress things ...
    }
});
```

instead of using native XHR.

Working with :

- `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver`
- last commons-io / commons-fileupload librairies
- default glassfish web-core.jar